# Как срыть полосу прокрутки в QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, события, qlistwidget, qscrollbar

Как сделать так, чтобы в `QListWidget` появлялась полоса прокрутки только тогда, когда происходит само *действие*. 
*Действие* - прокрутка колесиком мыши.

Как думаете это возможно сделать? 
Я не могу найти информацию об этом. Благодарю за любую информацию.

Comment: Какое действие должно происходить?

Comment: Действие - прокрутка колесиком мыши.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ScrollBar(QScrollBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setMouseTracking - свойство поддерживает отслеживание мыши для виджета.
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        # VerticalScrollBarPolicy - свойство содержит политику вертикальной полосы прокрутки
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    # enterEvent - обработчик событий. Событие отправляется в виджет, когда курсор мыши входит в виджет.
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)   

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QScrollBar:vertical {              
                border: none;
                background: white;
                width: 3px;               
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
            QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
                stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
                min-height: 0px;
            }
            QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
                stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
                height: 0px;
                subcontrol-position: bottom;
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
            }
            QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
                stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
                height: 0 px;
                subcontrol-position: top;
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
            }
        """)


    # leaveEvent- обработчик событий, чтобы получать события оставления виджета, 
    # которые передаются в параметре события.
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


class MyListWidget(QListWidget, ScrollBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyListWidget, self).__init__()

    def Clicked(self, item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "Вы кликнули: "+item.text())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)        

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQT QListwidget Demo')
        self.resize(300, 150)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(grid)

        self.listWidget = MyListWidget(self)
        labels = ("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7",
                  "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10") 
        self.listWidget.addItems(labels)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.listWidget.Clicked)     

        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Add Element", self)        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addElement)

        grid.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1)

    def addElement(self):
        item = QListWidgetItem()
        ### --- позиционируемся в какую строку будем добавлять ---
        # Если в Первую(верхную) 
        itemNumber = 0
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Input Dialog", "Введите строку для добавления в listWidget")
        if ok and (text.strip() != ""):
            item.setText(text)     
            self.listWidget.insertItem(itemNumber, item)


def main(): 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду что. Допустим еже есть большое количество элементов в QListWidget, но полоса прокрутки нет. И как только пользователь наводит курсор на QListWidget и прокручивает колесо мыши оно появляется. Что-то наподобие автоматического скрывания ее если того не требуется.

Comment: @Michael Shcherbakov я изменил код, пробуйте.

Comment: Во, то что нужно. Класс!. Спасибо большое.